# How can I close a Google Chrome profile?

Tags: google-chrome, user-profiles, multiple-users

When I install Windows or Linux (Ubuntu/Mint), I start off by installing Google Chrome. I sign in and sync 4 users within Chrome (4 Gmail accounts).

My extensions are sync'd as well. There is a setting under `Settings > Advanced` Settings that says `"Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed"`. I **uncheck** this every time.

I have all of my tabs opened for 2 different profiles. If I close all of them (along with the window) for a single profile, my Google Voice extension and Gmail Notification extension of the closed profile will still make notification sounds.

It often distracts me as I think there is a text/email on the profile I am viewing. Is there a way I can completely close the Chrome profile that I "closed"? I know I can surely do so in task manager, but it seems like a hassle to have to do this every time.

Comment: are you using the official extensions or third-party?

Comment: some official and some third party. It happens using either of them.

Answer (score 2):

To reset your user profile, shut down Chrome and then open the following directory path:

- On Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\Your User Name\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\
- On Windows Vista, 7 or 8: C:\Users\Your User Name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\
- On Mac OS X: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/
- On Linux: ~/.config/google-chrome/

Delete the profile you believe is damaged. Most users will simply have a “Default” user profile, which is what you’ll want to delete. Restart Chrome and optionally login to Sync to restore your bookmarks and other goodies.

Further steps to manage the user profile are in the [Google Support Forum](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824)

**EDIT :** As your comments below suggest that the answer doesnt solve the problem. So on further research I found out that it is the behavior of chrome browser(version 22.0.1221.0). Find the bug-filed reference here: [Issue 139521](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=139521)

**EDIT 2 :** A related issue is the lack of a "Close Profile" option [Issue 130656](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130656) which should properly close all windows and background tasks

Comment: The issue doesn't only happen with me. I think I'm the only one who cares about it None of the profiles are damaged. I just want any profile to close all tasks (in task manager) associated with a given profile (when closing the window the profile is in).

Comment: This isn’t an answer to the question (at all). You may as well have suggested doing a repair-install.

Comment: I've had the issue as far back as version 18 (at least that I've noticed). Though your edit is helpful, it doesn't provide me with a solution.

Comment: its a bug in the chrome browser.. which they have not resolved yet.. So how  can you get the solution

Comment: Well I posted this hoping for a solution. I already knew it was a bug :/

Comment: if something is not present in a particular software.. how can others create it for you

Comment: A work-around? A hack? A third-party patch? A fork? That’s the point to asking.

Comment: if you are having one.. then be my guest to share it

Comment: For the record, the bug linked in the above post has been marked as closed.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature as of Aug 2018.

A ticket opened in Chromium project addresses this issue:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=130656

It has been stalling for 6 years and it's sad they are underestimating it so much, because many users use multiple profiles in attempt to avoid cluttered profile using heavy resources, but fail to check the once you open an profile it won't unload extension until you exit all Chrome windows.

Comment: Well, it WAS there for a bit then, because I've been clicking my user icon, then going down to Exit <username> and it closes all windows and tabs I have open for that chrome user.  But now it's not there anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I found is to **exit Chrome**, then lunch it again with a profile you need.
[[image: 1]]